# Can you guys breakdown this very long passage?

Tags: grammar

The idea that Wittgenstein is opposed to the whole style of thinking that would approach, for example, the problem of understanding how language functions by trying to construct a theory that elucidates what the meaning of expressions consists in goes against the idea that he is merely out to oppose a particular account of meaning.

Comment: I know this passage is difficult, but could you give us your best break down of the passage?

Comment: I agree with rajah. In all questions on this site, we need to see what the OP already understands and what efforts he put in to answer his own question. Having said that, is there a particular reason you need to understand this particular passage? If it's just idle curiosity, or to learn English, just forget it, it's not super useful for either purpose. If you need to understand it because you're taking a course in or reading a book on philosophy, then you should have been exposed to a lot of background material which will have made parsing the passage easier.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this will ultimately require a discussion of Wittgenstein's ideas, which is better suited for philosophy.SE.

Comment: @jimm101: If you're one of the users who closevoted as Primarily Opinion-Based, I beg to differmn (I closevoted for lack of prior research). The text is convoluted and clumsy, but perfectly valid syntactically (though a few more commas would certainly help the hapless reader parse it! :). There's no reason to suppose that spelling out the syntactic structure would require giving any significant consideration to the *meaning*, beyond what's baldly stated.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I voted to close, but not as opinion based.

Answer (score 3):

This sentence is comprised of 55 words, and would be hard for most readers to parse. Microsoft Word gives it a Flesch-Kincaid Grade level of 24.7.

I have placed one of the clauses in parentheses and nested the clauses.

- The idea that Wittgenstein is opposed to the whole style of thinking that would approach

  - (for example, the problem of understanding how language functions

    - by trying to construct a theory that elucidates what the meaning of expressions consists in)
- goes against the idea

  - that he is merely out to oppose a particular account of meaning.